# Seeing cookies in HTTP requests/responses

Tags: javascript, cookies, xmlhttprequest

I want to debug what cookies (`Set-cookie`) I am sending as part of an JavaScript `XMLHttpRequest` and the cookies received in the corresponding response object. Is there any way to do this?. I want to look at the request/response objects directly instead of checking `document.cookie` or using the JQuery cookie plug-in.

I've tried looking in Chrome web inspector but I've had no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see cookie values also in [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) console in Firefox.

Just install the plugin and press F12 to access it

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They'll show up in the Net tab of the Chrome Developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

Try using HTTP Analyzer .

You just start it and access your website and it captures all the requests and responses.

Plus it ain't browser specific captures data from all browser requests and responses.

Answer (score 1):

In ur chrome, press F12 go to resources tab, expand cookies and see data in the cookie. See below cookies from facebook.com

[image]